# Remove TFS Excluded Changes Without Undoing?

Tags: tfs

I downloaded a new branch from my team's TFS. I had some strange errors when trying to run the project, so I Cleaned, Rebuilt and Built the solution which fixed it. However, for some reason TFS is showing ALL of the downloaded binaries, packages and more in my Pending Changes even though we don't track those items in TFS.

I excluded those changes so that I could keep checking-in. However, I really don't want these hundreds of files to remain in my excluded changes. I don't want to Undo the changes because most of them are [add]s and I am assuming it would delete them on my machine. I don't want to check them in because I am worried it will mess-up our TFS repo in some way.

Is there a way to just make them go away from my Pending Changes window without taking any action? If not, what do you suggest? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TFVC: Add a .tfignore file to exclude the `packages` folder. It's possible you had one before but deleted it.

If you're using Git: Add a .gitignore file, for the same purpose.

Comment: Ahhh, that is a good thought. I thought this was very strange as I have used TFS for years and never had this happen. I will check on that. Thank you!

Comment: Okay this is really strange. We do have a .tfignore file and it even has packages\* as the first line but it just seems to be ignoring the ignore file and adding them anytime I clean and rebuild. My teammates do not seem to be experiencing this. So far it seems to just be me.